# I am having an issue updating a table_widget in PYQT5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

using the following code the file is being created and then read by the code to update the table_widget. The table is not being updated in the gui. Print statements show that the data is being read but the rows are left blank.

```
def rebuild_setup(self):
    try:
        print("Current working directory:", os.getcwd())

        # Get the file prefixes
        file_prefixes = [filename for filename in os.listdir() if filename.startswith('in_')]

        print("File prefixes:", file_prefixes)

        # Write the file pairs to the file
        with open('file_pairs.txt', 'w') as f:
            try:
                for filename in file_prefixes:
                    f.write(filename + ',out_' + filename[3:] + '\n')

                print (os.getcwd())
                print(os.path.abspath('file_pairs.txt'))
                print("File Rebuilt!")
            except Exception as e:
                print("An error occurred while writing to the file:", str(e))

        # Check if the file exists
        if os.path.exists('file_pairs.txt'):
            print("'file_pairs.txt' exists.")
        else:
            print("'file_pairs.txt' does not exist.")

        # Read the data from the file
        with open('file_pairs.txt', 'r') as f:
            self.file_pairs = [tuple(line.strip().split(',')) for line in f]

        print("File pairs:", self.file_pairs)

        # Update the table
        self.table_widget.setRowCount(len(self.file_pairs))

        for i, (in_file, out_file) in enumerate(self.file_pairs):
            print("Adding row", i, ":", in_file, ",", out_file)

            in_item = QTableWidgetItem()
            in_item.setText(in_file)
            print("In item text:", in_item.text())
            self.table_widget.setItem(i, 0, in_item)

            out_item = QTableWidgetItem()
            out_item.setText(out_file)
            print("Out item text:", out_item.text())
            self.table_widget.setItem(i, 1, out_item)
        self.table_widget.Update 
        self.table_widget.viewport().update()
        print("Table Rebuilt!")

    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", str(e))
```

Comment: you have `self.table_widget.Update` but it should be rather `.update()` (with lower `u` and with `()`). Don't you get error message when you run in console/terminal?

Comment: You should also ensure that the column count is consistent; if the count is known, then just do `self.table_widget.setColumnCount(<number of columns>)`, otherwise something like `setColumnCount(max(len(items) for items in table_data))`. Besides, `setItem()` automatically implies scheduling an update on the view; remember that, unless you're using custom widgets that base their painting on custom aspects or require immediate response to external events, if you find yourself trying to call `update()` or `repaint()` it's probably because you did something wrong, and doing that is useless anyway.

Comment: See: [QTableWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#details) details.